# Запись в бд(PostgreSQL) данных из списков в функции другого файла

Tags: python, postgresql

**Подскажите!!** У меня есть 4 генератора чисел и времени, сборочный файл для них, работающий в асинхронном режиме, конфиг для бд и файл для работы с базой данных, с которым и возникли проблемы(в понимании как должно работать). Не могу понять как сделать правильно и где вызов функции для запуска генератора и записи этих данных в бд... Имеющийся способ в коде для бд явно неправильный и не работает! Однако как передавать подобные значения и создавать из функции другого файла - не понимаю.
Код генератора:
`first_generator.py`

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

messages_list = [
    {
        "datetime": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",
        "any_int": int
    },
]

result = list()
wrapper = list()

async def first_generator(messages_list):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    for i in range(2):
        time = datetime.utcnow()
        result.append({"datetime": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"), "any_int": i})
    wrapper = result

    for i in range(len(result)):
        print(result[i], "first_generator", "\n")
    print(wrapper, "wrapper", "\n")
    result.clear()

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(first_generator(messages_list))
```

Код сборщика:

```
import asyncio
from first_generator import main as one
from second_generator import main as two
from third_generator import main as three
from fourth_generator import main as four

async def main():
    for i in range(1):
        await asyncio.gather(one(), two(), three(), four())
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Код для базы данных:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import Error
from config import host, user, password, db_name
from first_generator import wrapper, main as ma

try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(
        host=host,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        database=db_name)

    connection.autocommit = True
    
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT version();"
        )
        print(f"Server version: {cursor.fetchone()}")

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            '''CREATE TABLE sensors_data (
                id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                time timestamp NOT NULL,
                any_int INTEGER NOT NULL);'''
        )

        print("Таблица успешно создана")

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        ma()
        data = wrapper
        cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO sensors_data (time, any_int) VALUES (%s, %s)", data)

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT time FROM sensors_data")
        print(f"Data: {cursor.fetchall()}")



except (Exception, Error) as error:
    print("Ошибка при работе с PostgreSQL", error)
finally:
    if connection:
        connection.close()
        print("Соединение с PostgreSQL закрыто")
```

Конфиг:

```
host = "127.0.0.1"
user = "postgres"
password = "postgres"
db_name = "postgres"
```